# Compojure session handling across concurrent requests

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have a long running POST request which updates the session with the requested result.

Now, when such concurrent POST requests are made from the same session, the updates done
in concurrent request don't get visibility across each other.

The effect is that, the session updates done in few concurrent request are eventually lost.

How is such a scenario normally handled ?

Answer (score 2):

So the scenario is, in short, like, this:

- long requests
- from the same user
- potentially concurrent

First clarification you should make is - is the concurrency inherent to the problem domain, or is it produced by user errors (e.g. clicking some control twice)?

In the latter case, both double submissions and double request processing can be prevented by lock-like mechanisms.

If concurrency *is* supposed to happen, you need to define the semantics of handling these concurrent requests.

Maybe last writer wins, or maybe the requests' operations are commutative and can be applied alltogether.

Once you determine these semantics, translating them to code should be easy. That said, it sounds like either Clojure's reference types (atom/agent/ref) or a database's facilities would be a better fit than a session object.

Comment: In this case, concurrent request from the same session should be allowed. Will look into the suggestions.